# Can two ng-app coexist in the same page?

Tags: angularjs

They way I understood it, it's better to use one module per functionality. For my demo application, I've create a module (with one, sometimes two controllers) for the user profile, cart, and product browsing.

Now that I've added the account and role management on the server side, I'm about to add a module as well that will deal with user's login and roles concern.

Knowing that login functionality will be required on almost all the pages, I'd like to know whether 2 modules can coexist on the same page?

On all my pages, there is no `ng-controller` directive, only `ng-app="cartModule"`. I din't see anywhere code that uses more than one module.

For instance, after logging, I need userId to navigate to the cart page, profile page, product page, and so forth. So far, I've hard-coded the `userId` just to allow me to keep coding. The alternative would be to merge all  the functionalities in one giant module.

Any idea about how to deal with common concerns?

Comment: move the Auth data and methods to a service that can be injected in any controller, other service or used in a route resolve promise

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a module, you can depend on other modules and have them made available as well:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['dataModule', 'someUiModule', ..., ])
```

So, do that.

You can have separate applications on the same page, but it doesn't really make that much sense to.

Comment: docs actually say to only bootstrap once per html page ... even though it's possible to do it more

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if you manually bootstrap angular:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var app1 = angular.module('app1',[]);
    var app2 = angular.module('app2',[]);
    ...  // Find the two DOM elements
    angular.bootstrap(element1, ['app1']);
    angular.bootstrap(element2, ['app2']);
});
```

In the HTML, make sure to remove all ngApp directives.